# Parent Child table record - Building SQL query

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Here is my table and data of these tables

Table name: **Code**

```
CID Code
1   abc
2   def
3   xyz
```

Table Name : **Details**

```
ID  Name    CID
1     a       1
2     b       2
```

**Resultant Table:**

```
ID      Code    Name
1       abc     a
2       abc     Null
3       def     b
4       def     Null
5       xyz     Null
6       xyz     Null
```

I nned to get all record from the code table and against each code I have to get all the rows from the details table, if some code have value their need value and if not then Null

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for the cartesian product:

```
SELECT
    c.CID * d.ID AS ID,
    c.Code,
    CASE
        WHEN c.CID = d.CID THEN d.Name
        ELSE NULL
    END AS Name
FROM Code c
CROSS JOIN Details d
```

Although cartesian products are quite slow for larger tables... so be sure that this is what you really want.