# Parent Child table record - Building SQL query

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parent Child table record - Building SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069595/parent-child-table-record-building-sql-query)

Here is my table and data of these tables

Table name: Code

```
CID     Code
1       abc
2       def     
3       xyz
```

Table Name : Details

```
ID  Date        Value1  CID
1   1/1/2009    12      1       
2   1/1/2009    25      2
3   1/1/2009    18      3
4   1/2/2009    36      1
5   1/2/2009    45      2
6   1/3/2009    19      1
```

Resultant Table:

```
Date        Value1  CID     Code
1/1/2009    12      1       abc
1/1/2009    25      2       def
1/1/2009    18      3       xyz
1/2/2009    36      1       abc
1/2/2009    45      2       def
1/2/2009    Null    3       xyz
1/3/2009    19      1       abc
1/3/2009    NUll    2       def
1/3/2009    Null    3       xyz
```

I need to get all record from the code table and against each code I have to get all the rows from the details table, if some code have value their need value and if not then Null

Thanks

Comment: @OMG; Its not duplicate, data is different. plz check Thanks

Comment: @Muhammad: different data or not, it's almost the same structure *and the same request*

Comment: I did using cross join, but it not give me proper result, it will return 18 rows, but I need 9 rows as in resultant table.

Comment: Is there an easy way to insert tab delimited data like this into SQL server and have it implicitly define columns?

Comment: @aaronis: No, columns and column values need to be separated by commas.

Comment: @Muhammad: It is the same thing... You need to `cross join` your dates with your codes. Then you can join to your `Details` table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Muhammad Akhtar, Have a look at this. Let me know if it helps

```
DECLARE @Code TABLE(
        CID INT,
        Code VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO @Code SELECT 1,'abc' 
INSERT INTO @Code SELECT 2,'def'      
INSERT INTO @Code SELECT 3,'xyz'

DECLARE @Details TABLE(
        ID  INT,
        Date DATETIME,
        Value1 INT,
        CID INT
)

INSERT INTO @Details SELECT 1,'1/1/2009',12,1        
INSERT INTO @Details SELECT 2,'1/1/2009',25,2 
INSERT INTO @Details SELECT 3,'1/1/2009',18,3 
INSERT INTO @Details SELECT 4,'1/2/2009',36,1 
INSERT INTO @Details SELECT 5,'1/2/2009',45,2 
INSERT INTO @Details SELECT 6,'1/3/2009',19,1 

SELECT  v.Date,
        d.Value1,
        v.CID,
        v.Code
FROM    (
            SELECT  DISTINCT
                    d.Date,
                    c.CID,
                    c.Code
            FROM    @Details d, @Code c
        ) v LEFT JOIN 
        @Details d  ON  v.CID = d.CID 
                    AND v.Date = d.Date
```

Comment: I will not be able to check right now, that is my personal email. Will reply when i get it a little later.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  t.* , d.value1
FROM (SELECT * FROM ((SELECT DISTINCT date FROM details) t CROSS JOIN code )) t 
      LEFT JOIN details d ON t.cid = d.cid and t.date = d.date
ORDER BY date, cid
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a `LEFT JOIN` between the Code table and the Details table, as indicated by the possibility of missing data in the result. The final query is left as an exercise, because this looks exactly like an exercise.

Comment: @Mohammad Looks like your professor found you.